# Create two dimensional array

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to create an array that holds multiple arrays, and each next array has the same values the previous one has, plus the new one.

Ex: `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`

Here is a fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/zLd3pqzz/

The problem is that all arrays are the same

Comment: You want `.slice`, not `splice`. `.splice` does *not* return a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead of [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
return innerArr.slice(0) // returns copy of original
//              ^^^^^
```

```js
var outerArr = [],
    innerArr = [];
    
function fillInner(data) {
    innerArr.push(data);
    return innerArr.slice(0) //returns copy of original
}

function fillOuter(data) {
    outerArr.push(fillInner(data));
    console.log(outerArr);
}

fillOuter(1);
fillOuter(2);
fillOuter(3);
```

Comment: yeah that was a typo from my point I wanted slice not splice, but the thing is when I open console and click the Array on the first result, it's the same as the final one. I guess it should be like that, or am I being dumb and I am thinking something different ? Because that's what I think is the problem (if it even is a problem).

Comment: the main problem is, the use of splice does not return an error. it just does nothing, in this case.

Comment: yeah I know, like I said I wanted to use slice, but I mistakenly typed splice, but the result is the same. So my question is, am I misunderstanding something or everything works ?

Comment: yeah I'm just dumb, thanks for the correction and the time :)